# Merging text files without a blank line at the beginning of the text file

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I am merging multiple text files into one using VB.Net. It merges the text files correctly, however there is a blank line appearing at the top of the text file, this means I can not read the text file correctly. Any idea on how to remove this blank line would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code that we have.

```
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines("7UP.txt")
Dim firstLine As String = lines.First
Dim lastLine As String = lines.Last

Using addProducts = File.AppendText("Top5.txt")
    addProducts.WriteLine(lines.First)
    addProducts.WriteLine(lines.Last)
End Using

lines = File.ReadAllLines("Americano.txt")

Using addProducts = File.AppendText("Top5.txt")
    addProducts.WriteLine(lines.First)
    addProducts.WriteLine(lines.Last)
End Using

lines = File.ReadAllLines("AppleJuice.txt")

Using addProducts = File.AppendText("Top5.txt")
    addProducts.WriteLine(lines.First)
    addProducts.WriteLine(lines.Last)
End Using
```

Comment: what problem with .Trim()?

Comment: where will I place the .Trim()?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you only the lines that have data:

```
Dim lines As String() =
    File.ReadAllLines("7UP.txt").
    Where(Function(x) x.Trim <> String.Empty).
    ToArray()
```

---

You might want to start organising your code something like this to make it more manageable:

```
Private Sub PerformMerge()

    Const top5File As String = "Top5.txt"

    MergeData(GetLinesWithData("7UP.txt"), top5File)
    MergeData(GetLinesWithData("Americano.txt"), top5File)
    MergeData(GetLinesWithData("AppleJuice.txt"), top5File)

End Sub

Private Function GetLinesWithData(sourceFile As String) As String()

    Return File.ReadAllLines(sourceFile).
        Where(Function(x) x.Trim <> String.Empty).
        ToArray()

End Function

Private Sub MergeData(lines As String(), destinationFile As String)

    Using addProducts = File.AppendText(destinationFile)
        addProducts.WriteLine(lines.First)
        addProducts.WriteLine(lines.Last)
    End Using

End Sub
```